# I used Google's Find My Phone to factory reset my phone since I lost it but before that happened, I got my phone back

Tags: hardware, google

So, I headed out one day and lost my phone. I head to see ways to get it back and saw that you can factory reset it through Google's Find My Phone. Now, someone gave it back and I'm stuck because if I go online on that phone, it may be factory reset. How can I prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you reset your phone using the Android Device Manager, there's a good chance it's already gone. Online means connected to the internet, and if mobile data was still on while you clicked the erase button, there's no way to undo that, as far as I know. Luckily, you can still recover some data when you sign in to your Google account on your phone, namely apps, settings and maybe some photos (if you used Google Photos).

Comment: I opened the phone and it was untouched by the person that got it. It wasn't connected to the internet since mobile data was turned off and I only used a laptop to tell Google to factory reset it, which it said won't happen as long as it is not online.

Comment: Using [this](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6160500?hl=en&ref_topic=6160499), I can only say this: try getting your data off that device just in case. There's a good chance the moment you reconnect your phone to the internet your phone will be wiped, but I'd suggest trying to [disable Android Device Manager](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/3265955), go online, then re-enable it.